# Connecting Grass with R

Tags: grass-gis, r

I need help to connect R with Grass. In RStudio when I send the line:

```
loc <- initGRASS("C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/bin/i386", home=tempdir(), override=TRUE)
```

It says:

```
Error in system(paste("g.dirseps.exe -g", shQuote(Sys.getenv("WINGISRC"))),  : 
  'g.dirseps.exe' not found
```

Guys, can you help me, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are your grass binaries really in "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.1.0/bin/i386"? The "gisBase" argument is the path to your GRASS install.

Something like this:

```
loc <- initGRASS("C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS 6.4.2", home=getwd(),  
                 gisDbase="GRASS_TEMP", override=TRUE )
```

Here is an example R/GRASS session that calculates the 3x3 surface relief ratio.

```
# Load package and set GRASS environment
require(spgrass6)
setwd("D:/TEST")
loc <- initGRASS("C:/Program Files (x86)/GRASS 6.4.2", 
       home=getwd(), gisDbase="GRASS_TEMP", override=TRUE )

# IMPORT IMAGINE (img) RASTER TO GRASS FORMAT AND SET REGION (EXTENT)
execGRASS("r.in.gdal", flags="o", parameters=list(input="dem.img", output="DEM"))
  execGRASS("g.region", flags="a", parameters=list(rast="DEM", res=as.character("30"),
            align="DEM") )

# Calculate surface relief ratio and export to img format
execGRASS("r.neighbors", flags="overwrite", parameters=list(input="DEM", output="mean", 
          method="average", size=as.integer(3)) )
execGRASS("r.neighbors", flags="overwrite", parameters=list(input="DEM", output="min", 
          method="minimum", size=as.integer(3)) )
execGRASS("r.neighbors", flags="overwrite", parameters=list(input="DEM", output="max", 
          method="maximum", size=as.integer(3)) )                 
execGRASS("r.mapcalculator", flags="overwrite", parameters=list(formula="(mean - min)/(max - min)",
          outfile="srr" ) )                   
execGRASS("r.out.gdal", parameters=list(input="srr", format="HFA", type="Float32", 
          output="srr3.img", nodata=-9999) )

# Clean up temp rasters       
execGRASS("g.remove", parameters=list(rast=c("mean", "min", "max", "srr")) )    

# Clean up GRASS workspace
unlink(paste(getwd(), "GRASS_TEMP", sep="/"), recursive=TRUE)
  file.remove(paste(getwd(), ".grassrc6", sep="/"))
```

Comment: thank you a lot, it works. But, it is another problem which I didn't notice before. When I run the next line: **library("spgrass6")** , it says: GRASS GIS interface loaded with GRASS version: **(GRASS not running)**

Comment: That is not an error just a package loading message. Although, I do not understand what you mean by "run next line". You should be loading the package before running "initGRASS". I expanded my answer to provide a brief example of an spgrass6 session.

Comment: how does this work on linux?

Comment: ok its `/usr/lib/grass72` if you have 7.2 installed. otherwise check with `grass<<your version here>> --config path`